# Get a model's property value from within a custom attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, attributes, data-annotations

I have a custom attribute called `FileLink` that uses `DisplayForModel()` to generate an `ActionLink` to a controller with an ID value.

The attribute looks like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class FileLinkAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public string IdPropertyName { get; set; }

    public FileLinkAttribute(string actionName, string controllerName, string idPropertyName)
    {
        ActionName = actionName;
        ControllerName = controllerName;
        IdPropertyName = idName;
    }
}
```

Is it used in a viewmodel, like so:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int? TargetId { get; set; }

    [FileLink("SomeAction", "SomeController", "TargetId")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a custom `MetadataProvider` derived from `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` that puts the attribute values into the metadata AdditionalValues as so:

```
    // retrieve the values to generate a file link
    var fileLinkAttributes = attributes.OfType<FileLinkAttribute>();
    if (fileLinkAttributes.Any())
    {
        var fileLinkAttribute = fileLinkAttributes.First();
        metadata.AdditionalValues["FileLinkAttribute"] = fileLinkAttribute;
        metadata.TemplateHint = "FileLink";
    }
```

The goal is to have `DisplayForModel` call the `DisplayTemplate` below to generate a link with the value in `TargetId` from `MyViewModel`. So if `TargetId` is 5, the link will be "SomeController/SomeAction/5"

```
// This DisplayTemplate for use with the "FileLinkAttribute"
//
// Usage: [FileLinkAttribute("ActionName","ControllerName","IdPropertyName")]

var fileLinkAttribute = (FileLinkAttribute)ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["FileLinkAttribute"];

var targetId = *<GET VALUE OF CONTAINER MODEL IdPropertyName>*;

@Html.ActionLink((string)ViewData.Model, fileLinkAttribute.ActionName, fileLinkAttribute.ControllerName, new { Id = targetId}, null)
```

With all this in place, I am unable to access the containing object to pull the property value from TargetId. I have tried to do this within the Attribute, within the Provider, and within the DisplayTemplate, with no luck.

Is there a way or place I can access this value to accomplish my intent to read a property value from the viewmodel object containing the attribute?

Answer (score 1):

After reading this post describing the purpose of `modelAccessor` in a custom DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider:

[What is the "Func<object> modelAccessor" parameter for in MVC's DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412392/what-is-the-funcobject-modelaccessor-parameter-for-in-mvcs-dataannotationsmo)

I was able to piece together this (very hackish) solution implemented in the custom provider:

```
    // retrieve the values to generate a file link
    var fileLinkAttributes = attributes.OfType<FileLinkAttribute>();
    if (fileLinkAttributes.Any())
    {
        var fileLinkAttribute = fileLinkAttributes.First();

        // modelAccessor contains a pointer the container, but the type is not correct but contains the name of the correct type
        if (modelAccessor.Target.GetType().ToString().Contains("System.Web.Mvc.AssociatedMetadataProvider"))
        {
            // get the container model for this metadata
            FieldInfo containerInfo = modelAccessor.Target.GetType().GetField("container");
            var containerObject = containerInfo.GetValue(modelAccessor.Target);

            // get the value of the requested property
            PropertyInfo pi = containerObject.GetType().GetProperty(fileLinkAttribute.IdPropertyName);
            string idPropertyValue = pi.GetValue(containerObject, null).ToString();
            fileLinkAttribute.IdPropertyValue = idPropertyValue;
        }

        metadata.AdditionalValues["FileLinkAttribute"] = fileLinkAttribute;
        metadata.TemplateHint = "FileLink";
    }
```

I am not sure how to derefence a Func to get it's actual target, and the type name comes out all munged wierdly in this example, such as

> "System.Web.Mvc.AssociatedMetadataProvider+<>c__DisplayClassb"

So I convert to a string to check if it contains "System.Web.Mvc.AssociatedMetadataProvider". Probably not the best thing but this is the only way I could get it to work.

Oh, I also added a 4th property to the attribute to contain the value:

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class FileLinkAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public string IdPropertyName { get; set; }
    public string IdPropertyValue { get; set; }

```
public FileLinkAttribute(string actionName, string controllerName, string idPropertyName)
{
    ActionName = actionName;
    ControllerName = controllerName;
    IdPropertyName = idPropertyName;
}
```

}

and in the DisplayTemplate I do:

```
var modelId = fileLinkAttribute.IdPropertyValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be an editor template for strsing or object as that'swhat you are applying the attribute on. So inside `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/string.cshtml`:

```
@model string

@{
    var fileLinkAttribute = (FileLinkAttribute)ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["FileLinkAttribute"];
    var targetId = fileLinkAttribute.IdPropertyName;
}

@Html.ActionLink(Model, fileLinkAttribute.ActionName, fileLinkAttribute.ControllerName, new { Id = targetId}, null)
```

and in your main view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
```

Comment: targetId should be the value of the property named in IdPropertyName, not the value of IdPropertyName itself. i.e. one level of indirection.

Comment: @CodeGrue, the metadata and thus the editor template applies on the property you are decorating with the custom attribute. So you might need to decorate your model if you want to access other properties.